# Subtract 1 row from each row in a tibble (R, dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This should be simple ... Rowwise ops in dplyr

```
#tibble
a=tibble(a=1:4,b=1:4,c=1:4)

#one row tibble to be subtracted from first one
b=tibble(a=5,b=5,c=5)

#well, this won't work
a-b

Error in Ops.data.frame(a, b) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

Of course, the workaround is to replicate the tibble's row ... but not elegant

```
#replicating
c=tibble(a=rep(5,4),b=rep(5,4),c=rep(5,4))

#works
a-c
```

But shouldn't this work with some rowwise operation?

```
a %>% rowwise %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~.-b))
```

it doesn't

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1     0     0     0
2     0     0     0
3     0     0     0
4     0     0     0
```

**EDIT: A compilation of answers**

First, a clearer formulation of the problem:

```
#tibble
a <- tibble(a=1:4,b=1:4,c=1:4)

#one row tibble to be subtracted from first one
b <- tibble(a=5,b=2,c=1)

#objective: turn this into a full-dplyr one-liner
a - b[rep(1,nrow(a)),]
```

Now, solutions:

```
#Gregor's answer below is very clean
a %>% {. - b[rep(1, nrow(.)), ]}

#Full-dplyr is just slightly longer
a %>% {. - slice(b, rep(1,nrow(.)) ) }

#Ronak's answer is most compact
purrr::pmap_dfr(a, ~. - b)

#without the namespace even better:
pmap_dfr(a, ~. - b)
```

Comment: To clarify your question: are you asking why your rowwise operation won't work, or are you asking for a cleaner way of subtracting the values in b from those in a?

Comment: Fair question. Just the cleanest way possible.

Comment: Actually, now I am curious why rowwise can't do this.

Comment: Replicating can be a simple 1-liner: `a - b[rep(1, nrow(a)), ]`

Comment: Gregor: yes, though that's not tidyverse syntax and it requires you repeat a within the brackets

Comment: @inferator `a %>% {. - b[rep(1, nrow(.)), ]}` there's your tidyverse syntax.

Comment: I like this. `a` only appears on the left side of the pipe, which makes copy and pasting that snippet on the right a breeze. It's similar to `a - b %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow({{a}})))` discussed further down, but better, because now repetition of `a`.

Comment: Just to point out that `t(t(a) - unlist(b))` is WAY faster than pmap_dfr. Like 20 times faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay in `tidyverse` you can use `pmap_dfr` which will help in rowwise operation for multiple columns.

```
b=tibble(a=5,b=2,c=1)
purrr::pmap_dfr(a, ~. - b)

#   a  b c
#1 -4 -1 0
#2 -3  0 1
#3 -2  1 2
#4 -1  2 3
```

In base R,  you can do

```
t(t(a) - unlist(b))

 #     a  b c
#[1,] -4 -1 0
#[2,] -3  0 1
#[3,] -2  1 2
#[4,] -1  2 3
```

Note that I have changed the values of `b` for clarity.

Comment: `b` in `pmap_dfr` could reference `a$b`, not the tibble `b`. How does pmap know where to look?

Comment: Only a row is passed as a vector to the function in `pmap_dfr` so it does not have access to the whole column. If you would have to access the column then you would need to do `a$b`. If we are using only `b` then there is no conflict and it refers to the dataframe `b` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using long-formatted data frames makes these types of operations consistent. The trick here is to create a row ID, pivot longer, join, and then pivot wider.

```
library(tibble)

#tibble
a <- tibble(a=1:4,b=1:4,c=1:4)

#one row tibble to be subtracted from first one
b <- tibble(a=5,b=5,c=5)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

a_pivot <- a |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> # create a row ID so we can pivot_wider
  pivot_longer(cols = c(everything(), -id), values_to = "values_a")

b_pivot <- b |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_to = "values_b")

ab_pivot <- left_join(a_pivot, b_pivot, by = c("name")) |> 
  mutate(values = values_a - values_b) |> 
  select(id, name, values) |> # remove other columns for the pivot_wider
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = values) |> 
  select(-id)
```

Comment: That is a great didactic example, but the code is rather long.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` only solution:

```
library(dplyr)

x = nrow(a)
b <- b %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each =x))

a - b
```

```
   a  b  c
1 -4 -4 -4
2 -3 -3 -3
3 -2 -2 -2
4 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: building on this: `a - b %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow({{a}})))`

Answer (score 0):

Edited to reflect OP's edits...

I think this is what you want:

```
b=as.numeric(c(5,2,1))

#well, this works
a-b

> a-b
   a  b  c
1 -4 -4 -4
2 -3 -3 -3
3 -2 -2 -2
4 -1 -1 -1
```

Of course

```
b=as.numeric(tibble(a=5,b=2,c=1))
```

works. Or if you actually do want to save b as a tibble for other use...

```
b=tibble(a=5,b=2,c=1)
a-as.numeric(b)
```

works too. Note the text of the error message:
"Error in Ops.data.frame(a, b) :
‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames" tells you this.

Comment: This would subtract colwise not rowwise. Admittedly, my example wasn't good enough. Ronak changed the values from 5,5,5 to 5,2,1.